# Telegram bot, Python, работа с фото

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Недавно начал учится писать ботов для телеграма на языке python, используя библиотеку telebot.
Мне нужно получать от пользователя фото и сохранять его в БД для дальнейшей пересылки. Где-то слышал, что можно сохранять фото не напрямую, а просто узнавать его id и в последствии сохранять только его в БД.
Знаю как получить id полученной фотографии, а как с его помощью выслать фото и возможно ли это вообще?

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
def photo(message):
   idphoto = message.photo[0].file_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ оказался очень простым..

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
def photo(message):
   idphoto = message.photo[0].file_id
   bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, idphoto )
```